# Make own JOIN statement with NotORM

Tags: php, sql, mariadb, notorm

I use [NotORM](http://www.notorm.com/) library for smoother way to work with DB. But I can't get JOIN work as I want. I want to make a query like this:

```
SELECT 
  blog.*,
  COUNT(blog_post.id) AS total 
FROM
  blog 
  LEFT JOIN blog_post 
    ON blog_post.blog_id = blog.id 
GROUP BY blog.id ;
```

This is what I made in PHP with NotORM library:

```
$this->db->blog()
    ->select('blog.*')
    ->select('COUNT(blog_post.id) AS total')
    ->joins('blog', 'LEFT JOIN blog_post ON blog_post.blog_id = blog.id')
    ->group('blog.id');
```

Unfortunately, it will make query like this:

```
SELECT 
  blog.*,
  COUNT(blog_post.id) AS total 
FROM
  blog 
  LEFT JOIN blog_post 
    ON blog.blog_post_id = blog_post.id 
GROUP BY blog.id ;
```

Why does it refer for `blog.blog_post_id`, when I wrote my own statement? Have someone experienced this?

Comment: What is `joins`? I don't see either in API or in the code any function with this name. But here is what I see in API: "If the dot notation is used for a column anywhere in the query ("$table.$column") then NotORM automatically creates left join to the referenced table." So, it appears that your `joins` does not work because there is no such method, while the automatic logic kicks in.

Comment: Yea, I found it in the source code afterwhile, method `joins` is used to enable or disable JOINs. So when you call `->joins(false)` then it will omit the `LEFT JOIN` and use `FROM blog, blog_post` instead. I just found that one in some other question on the web, probably it has solution in older version. Problem is, that it creates automatic JOINs and I can't change the behavior. I found the solution, but I din't know, if I should post it here, since I had to make changes in the file `NotORM/NotORM/Result.php`.

Comment: I would be interested in the solution.

Comment: @DvdEnde sorry for late response. I think I solved it by editing NotORM library itself to support and change JOIN formats. But since I use Laravel and model relations, I don't need to worry about JOINs anymore.